# Bootstrap 4 tooltip does not work when jQuery is included

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, tooltip

I'm trying to get the bootstrap included tooltips to work. Whenever I try to display them, it outputs an error on my console saying that "TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function"

However, when I remove the jQuery embed from my bootstrap.js (I'm working with Laravel), it works fine - but of course my other js stuff isnt working anymore.

bootstrap.js:

```
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.bSel = require('bootstrap-select'); 
    window.highlightJs = require('highlightjs');
    window.ApexCharts = require('apexcharts');
    window.Cookies = require('js-cookie');
    window.sjcl = require('sjcl');
    window.ScrollProgress = require('scrollprogress');
    $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.BootstrapVersion = '4.3.1';
```

I've also tried moving the jQuery include up or down but it is not working either.

Comment: I don't see that you are importing bootstrap (nor popper) anywhere

Comment: I've just found out, that theres already jQuery included somehow

Comment: bootstrap tooltip is dependant on popperjs